# generating a list of options using a JList at the right click on a table java

Tags: java, netbeans

Hello i would like to generate a list of opitons on the click of a table row. I am using a JList and the table is design with the palette. The table's name is tabSitesTBL.
unfortunately the List is not showing up when a click on a row. 
This is my unworking code.
Thanks to help me.

```java
private void tabSitesTBLMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
    try{
        String options [] = { "voir","contacter","reserver"};
        JList maliste = new JList(options);
        maliste.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        jPanel1.add(new JScrollPane(maliste));
        jPanel1.revalidate();
        jPanel1.repaint();
        //options.setVisible(true);
    }catch(Exception ex){             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed similar functionality, adding the JList to a window and displaying it worked well. Ofcourse, you need to handle the dispose etc. in some way.

```
    jTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        private JWindow window = null;

        @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if(window != null) {
                window.dispose();
                window = null ;
            }
            if (e.getButton() == 3) { // e.isPopupTrigger() is not working on my Mac
                String options[] = { "voir", "contacter", "reserver" };
                JList<String> maliste = new JList<String>(options);
                maliste.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
                window = new JWindow();
                window.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(maliste));
                window.pack();
                window.setLocation(e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen());
                window.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

**Edit**: Added options for dispose. Clicking on the table disposes off the window.

Answer (score 0):

> i would like to generate a list of opitons on the click of a table row

Then you should probably be using a `JPopupMenu`. That is a popup menu is typically used in application when using a right click. A popup menu allows you to invoke an Action based on the item selected and the popup will then automatically close.

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for more information and examples.